# How to access content in an object literal?

Tags: javascript, oop, object-literal

Can someone tell me what the best way is to store content in an object literal and how to access it using my JS pattern? I can't seem to get it to work.

```
Namespace.object = {
    var data = [{"myid1" : "<p>My content 1</p>"}];

    method: function () {
        var myData = Namespace.object.data[0].id;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To store:

```
Namespace.object = {
    data: [{"myid1" : "<p>My content 1</p>"}],

    method: function () {
        var myData = Namespace.object.data[0].id;
    }
};
```

To access:

```
var theFirstData = Namespace.object.data[0];

var myId1 = Namespace.object.data[0].myid1;

// Alternatively...
var myId1b = Namespace.object.data[0]['myid1'];

Namespace.object.method();
```

Comment: Thanks. Got it to work! The the "myid1" value is pulled from the ID of the element, which is defined in the HTML. Is the best way to do this (using line #2 under "To access:" in your response), the following: Namespace.object.data[0]['' + myid1 +''];? (It will only work if those single quotes are inside the brackets)